# How do I reduce the distance between the border-bottom and parts of text?

Tags: css, underline

I'm currently building my website and I've run into a problem. [Here is the webpage.](http://luk-e.com)

I want to add 3px underlines to only the links, like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgRjL.png]

The line height of the text is 56pt, so the border-bottom is far too far away from the links. `text-decoration: underline` is too thin, and way too close.

They need to be about half this distance. As negative padding doesn't exist, how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: Please post some code. -1

Comment: Line-height is the only thing you could possibly adjust to change that.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now used to this code **(This is demo)**

**Css**

```
.HomeText p a {
color: red;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
.HomeText p a:hover:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:-3px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px red;

}
```

**[Demo LInk](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/anbs5/)**

Comment: answer 3 - will have to bookmark this! I can see some limitations with certain older browsers though.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've adjusted it to how I need now. I'm still very new to coding, no had never heard of using :after.

Comment: sadly, this won't work with longer links, though... i wanted to use this technique but went back to border-bottom because multi-line links only get an underline after the last line with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
display: inline-block;
height: 1.2em;
```

Haven't tested extensively, but seems to close the gap nicely in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:** Accept that css has limitations and work round them.

**Answer 2:** The only way I can thing of doing this is a using a span displaying it is a block and adding a border and padding to the bottom - this process will open up a whole other can of worms though floats blocks inline text etc. So I would go back to answer 1.

Answer (score -2):

did you try this?

```
   a {
    border bottom: 3px red;
    }
```